# Why does exception type affect what will, and won't, compile?

Tags: java, exception

I have two versions of code. In the first version type of exception which is throwed in Method() - `NullPointerException`, in the second version - `Exception`. However first version will compile but second won't compile. Why is this happen?

```
public class Demo
{
    static void Method()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("error");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String argv[])
    { 
        try
        {
            Method();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second version.

```
public class Demo
{
    static void Method()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("error");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String argv[])
    { 
        try
        {
            Method();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

stack trace for first version:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: error
    at Demo.Method(Demo.java:7)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:18)
```

Comment: Both versions are same?!

Comment: @normallyity OP said "doesn't compil

Comment: He fixed it - before both were same.

Comment: Fixed the title as well. I misunderstood the intent originally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `NullPointerException` is a so-called "unchecked" exception. You don't need to declare them in the `throws` clause.

However, a casual `Exception` is *not* unchecked, and you *do* need to declare in a `throws` declaration. You need to make `Method()` throw `Exception` in your second code snippet.

Unchecked exceptions are `RuntimeException`, `Error` and derivate classes. `NullPointerException` derivates from `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException` is a `RunTimeException` (or un-checked) and does not have to be handled at compile time. `Exception`, however, is considered a checked exception and must be either caught or thrown by any method which encounters it.

The second snippet can be fixed by changing the method declaration as follows:

```
static void Method() throws Exception
```

[Unchecked Exceptions - The Controversy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since your method "Method()" throws `Exception`, you have to declare it on the method signature:

```
static void Method() throws Exception
```

And it will compile.
Cheers!

Comment: I know about `throws`. I am interested in difference

Comment: Right! I upvoted fge's answer, which explains better what you want than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as second example:

```
public class Demo
{
    static void Method() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("error");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String argv[])
    { 
        try
        {
            Method();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This should compile fine,

Answer (score 1):

The code of Version 1 does not compile in java version 6 or lower, i guess you are using java 7.

Java 7 looks at compiletime witch exact exception type is beeing thrown. in case 1 it is a runtime exception witch musst not appear in the signatur of the method.